# How to add a relative path in python to find image and other file with a short path?

Tags: python, path, relative-path

My project folder arrange in the following way:

```
Project folder-> Program folder->program
              -> Image folder named images->image
```

Now when I try to deal with a image in my program with path `images/image1.png`?
An error happens.
Can add a relative path in python to find image with the  short path `images/image1.png`?

I do not want to move my image folder into program folder nor change the path by `../images/image1.png`?

Answer (score 9):

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #<-- absolute dir the script is in
rel_path = "../images/image1.png"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
```

and now u can use abs_file_path variable as path to your image

```
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "../images/"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
current_file ="image" + str(X) +".png"
file = open(abs_file_path+current_file,'r')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
After the modify, my program can find the image1.png by 'images/image1.png', however, there are many images in the folder named images, 
is there some way to make all images can be accessed by 'images/image**x**.png'

Comment: @XiangweiWang If you like the answer, press the checkmark

Comment: @joelgoldstick im not sure, but i think he will never accept this answer as solution :)

Comment: This is not the best solution, this does not cover a case where this script is imported from other script.