# cannot acces a image from file in html website

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web, file-upload

[output:Screen shot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1NkL.png)

```html
 <!-- Add icon library -->
<html>
 <body class="body">
 <center>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="card">
  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='file:/omkar.png')}}align="middle" />
  <h1>Omkar More</h1>
  <p class="title">Student DYPSOEA</p>
  <p>PUNE UNIVERSITY</p>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <
</div>
   </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The code from above gives only symbol of image not shows it**

Comment: Are running this page as static or using some server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476659/how-to-add-a-relative-path-in-python-to-find-image-and-other-file-with-a-short-p  this answer might help you

Answer (score 0):

try closing the img src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

and you have incorrect syntax of `img` tag, here is the correct one.

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='file:/omkar.png')}}" align="middle" />
```

```html
<html>

<body class="body">
  <center>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <div class="card">

      <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" align="middle">

      <h1>Omkar More</h1>
      <p class="title">Student DYPSOEA</p>
      <p>PUNE UNIVERSITY</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>

    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing `"` and space before `align="middle"`

see below html

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='file:/omkar.png')}}" align="middle" />
```