# Relative to Absolute path of images

Tags: image, directory, path

I'm trying to change the absolute path of my images to a relative path so that I can push to GitHub and let my other peers work on this project. However the relative path doesn't seem to work. I am not importing OS and doing any path handling however I suspect this may be the issue. I've attached a copy of the error/code and my current directory set up.
Thanks!
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WWvN.png)

[Directory Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r379Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this stack overflow question:
[How to add a relative path in python to find image and other file with a short path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476659/how-to-add-a-relative-path-in-python-to-find-image-and-other-file-with-a-short-p)

Essentially it has to take an absolute path so you can manually create that